# How to use the canvas element to take advantage of accelerated graphics

Tags: html5-canvas, hardware-acceleration

I have html page and I use a generic handler to get a byte array for my img control.

I have recently moved to using the canvas element.

I have got an image loaded into my canvas after I have loaded it into a hidden img variable.

I want to refresh/change this image as quickly as I can.

I have read that canvas takes advantage of hardware accelerated graphics.

is this handled automatically by the canvas element?  Do i need to add any additional code?

Do I need specific graphics card or is it down to the graphics driver installed?

This is my code so far:

I call a generic handler ashx page that returns

```
context.Response.BinaryWrite(data);
```

This loads an image into an Image variable

```
var myIMG= new Image();
```

And when it has hit the onload event of that image variable it draws onto the canvas:

```
    var c1 = document.getElementById("live1x4");
    var ctx1 = c1.getContext("2d");
    c1.setAttribute('width', '360');
    c1.setAttribute('height', '288');
    img1x4.onload = function () {
        ctx1.drawImage(img1x4, 0, 0);
    };
    img1x4.onerror = function () {
        $("#divMode5").html('error#1');
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html5 Canvas automatically uses any existing GPU to accelerate graphics when it can.

Just be sure you have the latest browser installed (some old browsers don't use the GPU).

If you're just drawing an offscreen img element to the canvas, that's GPU accelerated.

```
context.drawImage(myImageElement,0,0);
```

I see that you're using a byte array for something.  Therefore I should mention that .getImageData and .putImageData don't use the GPU for acceleration.

Comment: HI, thanks for posting.  You have answered the main points I had. I have just added the code I use.  I am worried that because I am using an image variable 1st that I am losing any performance gains I acquire using the canvas element. Is that right do you know?  Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing myIMG & img1x4 are the same?  If so then your drawImage is GPU accelerated.  BTW, you can do this shortcut to set canvas width/height: c1.width=360; c2.height=288;  Good luck with your project!

Comment: @markE - could you provide link where you read that canvas has gpu acceleration? Is that somewhere in specyfication of Canvas or is it just browsers implementation? Where I can read which browsers has gpu acceleration on Canvas?